# Option value selected for loop

Tags: php, forms, html-select

I am trying to create a `selected` value of the previous output.
(the user fills in a form , submits, returns to the form) And I want the selected value to be the value the user previously used.

The `vraagNummer` and `answer` are given in the url parameter and the dropdown menu of items available in the list are created in a for loop.
Now I got stuck on that part.. How do I create an option selected value if it is created in a for loop?

Usually I would just put in `option value = $vraagNummer selected> <?php echo $vraagNummer ?></option` but in this case that wouldn't work. I suppose?

Anyone knows how to fix this?
Same with the A/B/C/D. How do I put in the selected value of `answer` into the value previously selected while still keeping the others as an option.
With kind regards,

```
if(!empty($_GET['vraagnummer'])){
            $vraagNummer = $_GET['vraagnummer'];
            if(!empty($_GET['answer'])){
                $answer = $_GET['answer'];
            }
        }
        echo $vraagNummer;
        echo $answer;
        ?>

        <form id="start" method="post" action="index.php?test=true">
            <select name="question">
                <?php 
                for($i= 1; $i < $nRows+1 ; $i++){
                    ?><option value="<?php echo $i ?>">Question <?php echo $i?></option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <select name="result">
                <option value="A">Answer A</option>
                <option value="B">Answer B</option>
                <option value="C">Answer C</option>
                <option value="D">Answer D</option>

            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

Comment: `<option selected="selected ....>`

Comment: But because it is in a for loop, they are all given the selected class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply test the `$_GET['question']` against the current `$i` value in the loop using a ternary if

```
<form id="start" method="post" action="index.php?test=true">
    <select name="question">
<?php 
    for($i= 1; $i < $nRows+1 ; $i++){
        $sel = (isset($_GET['question']) && $_GET['question'] == $i) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
        echo '<option ' . $sel . ' value="' . $i .">Question ' . $i . '</option>';
    }
?>
    </select>
```

> Warning:
>
> Also be careful with the use of `empty()` when the variables can contain a zero as zero is considered as empty by the `empty()` function

Actually I would do your other dropdown like this

```
<select name="result">
foreach (range('A', 'D') as $char) {
    $sel = (isset($_GET['result']) && $char == $_GET['result']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option $sel value='$char'>Answer $char</option>";
}
</select>
```

Comment: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

Comment: Sorry a TYPO, I fixed it refresh the page and see changes

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm! And can I use the same with the `A/B/C/D` ?

Comment: Similiar, you will have to do the test for each `<option>`

Comment: Actually you could do your other select like I have shown above